# ERC223 and money loss

Tags: erc-20, erc-223

I am trying to understand what money loss case the [ERC223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) standard is trying to solve.

> If you send 100 ETH to a contract that is not intended to work with
>   Ether, then it will reject a transaction and nothing bad will happen.
>   **If you will send 100 ERC20 tokens to a contract that is not intended
>   to work with ERC20 tokens, then it will not reject tokens because it
>   cant recognize an incoming transaction.** As the result, your tokens
>   will get stuck at the contracts balance.

I thought this is solved by `approve` and `transferFrom` in ERC20? Since contracts that do not accept ERC20 tokens would not user `transferFrom` in order to fetch the tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Let me put this in simple words:

If a monkey is given with a mobile then it doesn't know what to do with it, it will throw away the phone since it can not eat it.

Similarly, a receiver contract (monkey) that cannot handle incoming ERC20 tokens (mobile) will discard them.

When I send the tokens to another person then the value is first deducted from my account and then it is increased in receiver's account. If the receiver address is not a person's address but a contract's address then the amount will be decremented from the my account but the contract can only receive those token if it is explicitly programmed to do so.(ERC223) If it is not then the tokens are lost. or forever decremented from our balance.

> I thought this is solved by approve and transferFrom in ERC20? Since contracts that do not accept ERC20 tokens would not user transferFrom in order to fetch the tokens?

No these two function are used to send tokens on behalf of somebody else. These function take parameter of the spender's and receiver's address.

Comment: But you could technically `approve` some tokens to a contract, which would then have to use the `transferFrom` to gain ownership of those tokens thus practically avoiding the problem of tokens being lost due to a receiver contract not being aware of the ERC20 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put things into context because there is a lot of confusion with Tokens, and some technical issues are often lexical issues. We unfortunately use token for two different things: a resource and its manager.

Or basically, a **token** is not really an resource/item you can own, store and exchange freely, in a peer-to-peer way. Instead, it is a type of distributed application, or dapp, that maintains a register of who has how much of a certain resource. The fact that it is a dapp has two important consequences: it is **autonomous** and **non-modifiable**. Therefore its behavior at conception is **final** and all changes to the register is also final.

With that said, when they speak of 'sending 100 ERC20', what is really meant is telling the dapp to lower the balance of the sender and raise that of the recipient on their register, regardless of the recipient. If the recipient is another dapp which has no method to communicate with the ERC20 Token, then it won't be aware about the resource you made available to it in the first place, even less how to use it. But the resource is still present. It is not lost, just wasted (hence the monkey analogy).

Now the approve() method is indeed one way to circumvent the issue, but it suffers from major design flaws:

- it transforms a 1-step, 1 party process to a 2-step, 2-party process. In other words, it is akin to dumping the credit card to go back to checkbooks, with all the known complications it entails.
- it is up to the sender, or their software client/wallet to use approve(), which few will do by lack of awareness. If it's not mandatory and makes things more complex, it won't be adopted.

Limiting the possible addresses in the Token registry to non-contract addresses is one way to solve the problem.

I hope that helps.